# Is Stack Overflow the right place to ask a question about code efficiency?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I posted the following question on Stack Overflow:

[Efficient Intersection and Union of Lists of Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957314/efficient-intersection-and-union-of-lists-of-strings)

There is disagreement as to whether it is on- or off-topic.  The concern is that my code already "works", although I need to find a more efficient approach since I need to run it in a huge loop.

Should this question be moved to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as some suggest, or is there anything I can do to improve the question to allow it to be on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Can a user migrate her own question (complete with existing comments and answers) to a different site?

Comment: No, they cannot.

Comment: I believe that the question is appropriate for SO.  I vote to re-open the question.

Comment: I dislike the growing trend of closing stuff like this, especially when there is no automatic migration. I bet most users suggesting code review have never actually set foot on that site. But then, a question asking for more efficient ways is definitely at odds with SO's guidelines these days, and is in danger for being closed as "too broad" even if we vote to reopen it.

Comment: Also since I don't have 3K reputation, is there any way to see how many re-open votes a question of mine has?

Comment: @PurpleVermont That's a privilege that, if I remember right, is rewarded at 250 rep.

Comment: @Pekka in the case of somewhat off-topic but high quality questions it would indeed be nice if people tried to migrate (by flagging) without closing (unless its one of the migration path closures)

Comment: for what it's worth, the post I liked (as well as many others) seems to provide precedent for code efficiency / performance questions to be asked on SO -- have the standards changed?

Comment: that should say **linked** above (not liked).  Too late to edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the sort of question I personally find *really* useful; optimizing common algorithms for uncommon data sets can be a very tedious... And often just *doesn't get done* because unless someone's already done the leg-work it's too much of an investment. So I love seeing them on SO.

That said, you have a small problem with your question as it stands:

> The accepted answer here Efficiently compute Intersection of two Sets in Java? looked extremely helpful but (likely because my sets are small (?)) I haven't gotten much improvement by using the approach suggested in the accepted answer.

Give us some more information on your sets. *How* small? *How many of them?* If someone's looking to optimize for a situation wholly different from what's been considered in the previous question, it's important that *they have a good understanding of the nature of that situation!* Ideally, folks would be able to *test* their solutions against data of a certain form (if not necessarily specific *data*).

Do that, and I think it'd be a perfectly good question.

Comment: Done, and thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Leaving aside the possible improvements to your question that [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215286/200582) described, the question absolutely should not have been closed on the basis that it would also be on-topic on Code Review. There was already another case of this "it's on topic on Code Review, so it's off topic on Stack Overflow" reasoning [in this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214787), and it was [flatly contradicted by moderator Bill the Lizard♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214790/200582), to near-unanimous agreement by the community - at the time that I write this, his answer is currently on (+18/-1) score.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, your question as it stands now is more on-topic at CR - especially considering this sentence:

> My question is, **is there anything I can do to improve this**, given that I'm working with Strings which may be more time consuming to check equality than other data types.

Comment: What would be involved in getting it migrated over there?  It seems like migrating would be better than just duplicating it.

Comment: Also, why does SO have tags for `code-efficiency` and `performance` if those are off-topic for SO?